# Xamarin Forms Flyout page inside navigation page causes navigation bar issue in UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

I am using Flyout Page which is a start page and wrapped with navigation page. I am getting below navigation bar issue(shows title twice).

[image: Burger Menu Icon in between navigation bars]

Setting my start up page as "MainPage = new MainPage();" will fix the issue but I want it to be navigation page since my app has many pages which is not flyout.

Adding this line of code "NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);" fixes the issue in Android but not in UWP.

Kindly someone let me know if any workaround is there to fix in UWP.

My code below.
MainPage.xaml:

```
<FlyoutPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="HamburgerMenu.MainPage"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HamburgerMenu;assembly=HamburgerMenu"
         FlyoutLayoutBehavior="Popover">

<FlyoutPage.Flyout>
    <local:MenuPage x:Name="menuPage" IconImageSource="burger_icon.png"/>
</FlyoutPage.Flyout>
<FlyoutPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:ContactPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</FlyoutPage.Detail>
```

MainPage.cs:

```
 public partial class MainPage : FlyoutPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

ContactPage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="HamburgerMenu.ContactPage"
         Title="My Title">
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Order="Primary" IconImageSource="contacts.png" />
    <ToolbarItem Order="Primary" IconImageSource="todo.png" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Iam Content/Detail Page" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Xamarin Forms Flyout page inside navigation page causes navigation bar issue in UWP

The problem is `ContactPage` was placed in the `NavigationPage` by default with following line, and if you package the MainPage with `NavigationPage` also, it will render the page Title twice. That is why remove MainPage's container will fix issue.

```
<FlyoutPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:ContactPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</FlyoutPage.Detail>
```

> but I want it to be navigation page since my app has many pages which is not flyout.

If you want to make current page has no `NavigationBar` please call `SetHasNavigationBar` in the matched page, but not the `MainPage`. And **it will make the flyout button hidden at same time**.

```
public ContactsPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
}
```

For more please refer this [source](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/5.0.0/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/NavigationPageRenderer.cs#L678) code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I need flyout button to be shown. Any workarounds are there?. I thought of going for Shell page which works fine but I need to do lots of code changes to adopt to my existing project.

Comment: The good practice is keep original  code that remove MainPage's navigatepage container, when you want to hidden the page's navigation bar, please set the matched page's title  as null.